# Create/update ListView with custom layout (background)

Tags: android, listview

I have problem to change the backgroud for the list view from a func

The listView receive the data from URL by JSON encdoe like that:

```
{"results":[
    {"db_id":"6","discount":"active","db_description":"bla bla bla ","db_num":"137","db_num2":"260"},
    {"db_id":"14","db_type":"discount","db_description":"blaaaaaaa","db_num":"39","db_num2":"46"},
    {"db_id":"18","db_type":"discount","db_description":"blaaaaaaa","db_num":"335","db_num2":"456"},
]}
```

my code:

```
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        QueueActivity.this, QueueList,
                        R.layout.queue_row, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_NUM, TAG_NUM2, TAG_IMAGE},
                        new int[] { R.id.qid, R.id.description, R.id.num, R.id.num2, R.id.list_image });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

onListItemClick i can simplay update the background

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_taken_background);   
       TextView textid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.queueid);
       textid.setText("NEW TEXT")
}
```

but i need to update the background from a func as well 
how can i do it ?

for ex, the command  ***new FuncName().execute("2");*** will set the backround resource for 2nd row to "R.drawable.listview_taken_background"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView.getChildAt(int index)` to return your `View` at this position then edit its background.

Comment: View listView = getListView().getChildAt(0);
listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_taken_background); I Get NullPointException

Comment: Are you sure you call this after you fill the ListView?

Comment: yes 100%. the function is called after the setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Try casting it as a ViewGroup instead of View