# Android ListView scrolling to position

Tags: android, listview, scroll, winamp

```
private void setListviewSelection(final ListView list, final int pos) {
    list.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            list.setSelection(pos);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++)  {
                    View v = list.getChildAt(i);

                    if (i == pos && v != null)
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, 51, 181, 229));
                    else if (v != null)
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a code I'm using to imitate a selection in my music player. The idea is that when user press Next or Previous button an element is highlighted in the `ListView`, but this is not working the way I want, because `setSelection` doesn't scroll smoothly and basically some elements are not highlighted correctly. For better explanation, what I'm actually trying to implement is a Winamp app which has that way of scrolling when you press next/previous button (when viewing your playlist).

Using `setSelectionFromTop()`, `smoothScrollToPosition()` didn't work correctly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/

Here is the solution which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update `Views` from the main thread. Move your code to the Main thread.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for my case, highlighting still "jumping" from one element to another.

Comment: Looks like **v** is returning null even do it is actually visible by an eye in the list.

Comment: Is there a reason for using a thread? You cannot update User Interface from outside the Main thread

Comment: Threads are useful maybe cause there are some heavy work that have to be done before updating a view in a list view. So that work must be done in a new thread. Then you can update ui in the ui thread using a Handler inside the new thread after the heavy work have been done.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah moving code to main thread doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah did you actually tried to run this code yourself ? When doing your way, highlighting is happening but scrolling of the list doesn't.

Comment: @ voloshyn I am stating facts: 1- you cannot update View from outside the Main thread. 2- ListView getChildAt() method should cast as a ViewGroup (check my answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310272/create-update-listview-with-custom-layout-background/12310511#comment16545107_12310511) and comment